# evaluate the bounds of iterator in the table given as a sequence?

Tags: functions, function-construction, hold

We know that `Table` has the attribute of `HoldAll` therefore an input provided as follows will not evaluate:

```
Table[i^2, {i, Sequence[0, 5, 1]}]
(* Table::iterb: Iterator {i,Sequence[0,5,1]} does not have appropriate bounds. *)
```

Is there a way to devise a scheme to circumvent the problem?

Comment: `Table[i^2, {i, ##}] &[0, 5, 1]`?

Comment: Why not just use `Table[i^2, {i, Range[0, 5, 1]}]`?

Comment: @Carl Woll this was a simple example. I needed to implement the other form at one occasion today.

Comment: It seems to me that any Table version that needs a Sequence as a second argument can be easily handled by using Range instead. What was your example where Range was insufficient?

Comment: @Carl I will update this question tomorrow morning.

Comment: How about `Table[i^2, Evaluate@Join[{i}, {0, 5, 1}]]`? Or, if you're bound to using `Sequence`, `Table[i^2, Evaluate@Join[{i}, {Sequence[0, 5, 1]}]]`?

Comment: @aardvark2012 - `Table[i^2, Evaluate@{i, Sequence[0, 5, 1]}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Heh. I was sure I tried that. But yeah, that one.

Comment: @BobHanlon The problem with this is that if `i` happens to have a global value before this call, it won't work.

Comment: You can also avoid the issue with `Range[0, 5]^2`

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason to ever try to evaluate something like:

```
Table[i^2, {i, Sequence[1, 5, 1]}]
```

instead of just:

```
Table[i^2, {i, Range[1, 5, 1]}]
```

For example:

```
foo = Sequence[1, 5, 1];
Table[i^2, {i, Range[foo]}]
```

> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25}

If you must create a new function that allows a [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence) object, then the following is simpler:

```
SetAttributes[table, HoldAll]

table[a_, {b_, HoldPattern[Sequence[c__]]}] := Table[a, {b, Range[c]}]
table[a__] := Table[a]
```

*(As @MichealE2 points out in the comments, one could have used {b, c} instead of {b, Range[c]} above, but I want to emphasize that using Range instead of Sequence is all that's needed, and that there is no real need to create a new `table` function)*.

Examples:

```
table[i^2, {i, Sequence[0, 5, 1]}]
table[i^2, {i, Sequence[3]}]
table[i^2, {i, 2}]
```

> {0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25}
>
> {1, 4, 9}
>
> {1, 4}

Comment: You don't really need `Range`: `table[a_, {b_, HoldPattern[Sequence[c__]]}] := Table[a, {b, c}]` works for me.

Comment: +1 ! I was merely doing random experimentation with the language.

Answer (score 0):

I constructed a method to overcome the issue:

```
SetAttributes[table, HoldAllComplete];

table[body_, tail_] := Module[{p, q, sym = Unique["x"]},
{p, q} = 
Map[(Hold[#] /. x_ /;(Developer`HoldSymbolQ[x] && !MemberQ[Names["System`*"],ToString[x]])
:> sym) &, {Unevaluated@body, Unevaluated@tail}];
Apply[Table, {p, q} /. {Hold[x_] :> x, Hold[x__] :> {x}}]
];

i = 10;
table[i^2, {i, Sequence[0, 5, 1]}]
(* {0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25} *)
```

Comment: @numbermaniac great ! You might want to add that as an answer. It never crossed my mind that it could be as simple. There are plenty of ways of doing things in MMA and I realize that not all approaches are efficient. Regardless, all approaches teach you a new way to look at the language